# Solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f = h f + h \int h f$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there a closed form solution to the following differential equation?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(i, t) = a h(i) f(i, t) + b h(i) \int \mathrm{d}i\ h(i) f(i, t)$$

Where $h(i)=C (i+1)^{-p}$ with $i\ge 0$, $p>1$ and $C$ chosen to ensure $\int h(i)=1$

In a discrete setting, $h$ could be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and I could write solution in terms of inverse Laplace transform of a $d\times d$ matrix below. Wondering if there's a way to extend this to the setting above

$$f(t)=\mathcal L^{-1}\left[(sI - a\ \operatorname{diag}(h) - b\ h\otimes h)^{-1}\right]f(0)$$

Motivation: this is a continuous extension of evolution of random difference equation $e=e-x<x,e>$ where $x\sim$ Normal(0, $\operatorname{diag}h$), more in this [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Comment: Did you try the Lie-Trotter product formula for operator exponential functions?

Comment: @JochenGlueck This formula looks interesting, but I couldn't make progress with it.... it feels like switching to limit representation makes things harder

Comment: Reposted [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686487/solving-frac-partial-partial-t-f-hf-int-mathrm-d-i-h-f) on math.SE